# Помогите разобраться с данным кодом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код

```
def F(x):
   return(x // 4) * ((60-x) // 4)

a=0
b=60
M=a
R=F(a)
for t in range (a, b+1):
  if (F(t) >= R):
    M=t
    R=F(t)
print(M+R)
```

Не могу понять как работает `F(t)`, насколько я понял строка `if (F(t) >= R):` в данном случае будет выполняться при условии что `t` будет либо равно либо больше 4. Но при таком условии у меня на бумаге получается что `M`= 4, а `R` = 16, и вывод у меня число `20`, что является ошибкой так как правильный вывод `88`.
Надеюсь понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У вас ошибка на бумаге. Не 16, а 14.
2. Цикл на 4 не заканчивается, а продолжается до 60. Последнее значение t попадающее в if - 32. R при этом получается 56. В сумме 88

Comment: А почему последнее значение именно 32?

Comment: @Tryr потому что при остальных значениях (33 и больше, до 60) F(t) меньше 56 и if не выполняется.